# Solspace Calendar always shows full week

Tags: solspace-calendar

I'm using solspace calendar to output events. Everything works well, the only issue is that for some reason, no matter what parameters I supply for date_range_start, date_range_end, and show_days, the tag always outputs an entire week. Here is the tag I'm using:

> {exp:calendar:cal
>            event_limit="4"
>            paginate="bottom"
>            category="public"
>            date_range_start="2016-02-25"
>            show_days="1"
>    }

This always gives back a full week of events. So, in this example, since the 25th is in the middle of the week, the cal tag outputs all events from 2/21 - 2/27 (sunday-saturday).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Calendar:Cal tag in Calendar 1.x assumes you want to display a full week or full month view, and automatically pads extra days to make it a full week. You'll need to simply just specify the [pad_short_weeks="n"](https://solspace.com/legacy_docs/calendar-1/cal/#pad_short_weeks) parameter to stop this from happening. :)